# constructor inheriting self python

Tags: python

I made a class which looks something like.

```
class NewInt:
  def __init__(self, x,y):
    self.holders = {"x":x,"y":y}
```

Now, I have a number say a dictionary. So everything is exactly same

except its not NewInt but a dict.Somethng like

```
 A  {"x": 3,"y":4}
```

So it is exactly of type NewInt except its a dictionary.

Is there a way i can do something like

```
this_int = NewInt(A)
```

I forgot but there was a special name to such constructor where assignment is done ??
Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand you... Try `this_int = NewInt(**A)`.

Comment: For more general cases, you might want to watch [PEP 3124](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3124/) which would introduce overloading to python, making it easier to make constructors that vary based on input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
A = {"x": 3,"y":4}
this_int = NewInt(**A)
```

By the way, it's looking like you're reimplementing [complex numbers](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric). Those are already built in to Python, try `complex(3,4)` or `3+4j`.

Comment: You may need to add an additional **kwargs argument for this to work when the dictionary has extra keywords, otherwise you'll get a TypeError for the unexpected extra keyword argument(s).